# How do I acquire the dependency 'gstreamer-sharp-1.0'?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, banshee

I have decided I would like to contribute to an open source project, so I am attempting to contribute to Banshee media player. I have got the latest commit from GitHub. When I try to compile the code using ./autogen, I get the following error:

configure: error: Package requirements (gstreamer-sharp-1.0 >= 0.99.0) were not met:
No package 'gstreamer-sharp-1.0' found

I have searched for a package containing this dependency using:

apt-cache search gstreamer-sharp-1.0

But it returns nothing. Could somebody explain to me in detail how I can get this dependency? I am on Ubuntu 14.04 if that helps.

Comment: Have you installed banshee on your Ubuntu? The installation should install the requirements.

Comment: Yes, I have banshee installed on Ubuntu. Wouldn't that only ensure I have runtime dependencies and not compile time dependencies though?

Comment: Possibly - maybe check the answer in [this thread](http://banshee-media-player.2283330.n4.nabble.com/Trouble-Building-Banshee-on-Linux-Mint-td4651646.html).

Comment: Here's the answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/510437/how-to-build-banshee-2-9-1-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to build Banshee using that post. I had to use './autogen.sh --prefix=/usr' to build 'gstreamer-sharp-1.0'. I also had to build 'gudev-sharp-3.0' from source.

Comment: @user2961850 I cant seem to compile banshee(from github). Could you make a deb file of the banshee you compiled and share that with us? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 btw.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer: ["how to build banshee 2 9 1 on ubuntu 14 04"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/510437/how-to-build-banshee-2-9-1-on-ubuntu-14-04) – user3159253

Thank you very much, I managed to build Banshee using that post. I had to use './autogen.sh --prefix=/usr' to build 'gstreamer-sharp-1.0'. I also had to build 'gudev-sharp-3.0' from source. – user2961850